# How can the csv file be efficiently implemented into Mathematica as a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

We are doing research on a great number of job advertisements. All NLP processes are executed by using Text Miner from SAS. The result of these processes is a transactional depiction of the texts in the following form: document, sentence, term, position. A sample file (csv) is attached to this mail.

Here’s my question:

How can the csv file be efficiently implemented into Mathematica as a list of lists:

The target format would be as follows:

```
{all job ads {job ad {sentence {terms separated by comma}}}}
or, referring to the above example: {{{{ auf, Basis, das, ...},{ sie, nehmen, kunden#anforderungen, ...}}}.
```

Attention should be paid to the fact that the numbering of the documents, sentences, terms, positions is done in an orderly manner but might show gaps between the documents, sentences and terms.

I would be very grateful if you could suggest a programme sequence by which this task could be solved as efficiently as possible.

PS. the first three variables (Dokument,Satz,Term_Position) define just the place of the terms in the list of lists. The list on the lowest level contain all terms within the same sentence (Satz) of the same document (ordered according the variable Term_Position and separated by a comma, without empty fields), the list on the second lowest level contain all sentences within the same document (Dokument), and so forth.

example from the file:

Dokument,Satz,Term_Position,Term
1,1,1,auf
1,1,2,basis
1,1,3,das
1,1,4,unternehmen#strategie
1,1,5,ermitteln
1,1,6,das
1,1,8,zukünftige informatikbedürfnisse
1,1,10,und
1,1,11,bringen

Comment: Can you give e few records as example of your data

Comment: It sounds like a task for `Database`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Example of the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcg03x18qpzmgz9/Testfile_jobinsight_2017.csv?dl=0